How to make the radius of a 3D pipe bigger without changing its thickness in unity
So, I need to have differently sized 3D pipes (such as this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.probuilder@6.0/manual/Pipe.html) in a unity project with a constant thickness. After looking around for a while I couldn´t find anything of use so I came here
First, I thought about modeling variations of the pipe, but that would decrease flexibility as I would have only a specific set of models. I also thought about doing something with the linerenderer and then creating a mesh from it but I can´t really see how that would work. I then thought that maybe I could have two circle models, one bigger than the other, and eliminate the overlapping parts, but I don´t know if unity even has support for that. I also need to be able to divide the pipe into a few different pieces which complicates things further. So I don´t have any good ideas on how to do this. Help would be heavily appreciated

Some Unity questions are on topic here, but you might do better asking this on [computergraphics.se]

To do objects like this you may need to do a mesh generation script with some parameters as:

Height (float)
Radius (float)
Thick (float)
HeightCuts (int)
LoopCuts (int)

For the code and understand it better i sugest to view as always some Brackeys video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=eJEpeUH1EMg

you could use spline for this.
i havent tried this but . you could define the path using spline and then instantiate cylinders on them .
